# Auto populating an html field using email recipients' email address

Tags: html, asp.net

I have created a survey for the employees within my workplace to complete. I'm trying to figure out how to auto populate the required email address field in the survey, with the recipients' address so they don't have to do it themselves.

The back end for the Content Management System which we have in place uses ASP.NET. I also used this CMS to create the form.

They will have reached the company survey page by being redirected through a preceding email, prompting them to complete the survey.

Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: You are probably going to have to be more specific with the CMS you are using, if the user has logged in, and    would not be a bad idea to post some code.

Comment: I'll try to clarify. The recipient will get an email which contains a link; this will bring them to the survey I created. At that point, I would like a field in the survey to be auto populated with their Email address. The CMS (Active Content Manager - Copyright 2006 - 2011 - The Active Network ) is just for myself and my admin to use to create the form; the recipient wont be logged into the CMS. I would like to show you some code, but the CMS doesnt allow us to edit the source code for the back end :\ All I have access to is the HTML/CSS/Javascript and the design editor.

Comment: Would not be a bad idea, but by the sounds of things, you would need to create the link like this.  
http:://example.com/path/to/the/survey?email=theiremail@example.com  
And then in the CMS grab that Get Variable and put it into the form.